# @ModelType causing syntax error even though Razor is registered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an MVC 3 app and a view with a single line:

```
@ModelType String
```

and this causes a "Syntax error" in Index.vbhtml, with no line or column specified. Research suggests the Razor view engine is not registered, but I have the following in my ~\Views\web.config:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Would @ModelType System.String work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind - it appears to be a known issue with MVC3 and VB:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8136

Comment: This link is now a 404

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
@model SomeNamespace.To.Your.Type
```